# C Bitwise Operation according to truth table

Tags: c, bit

My program has register of 8 bit namely `PC0,PC1,PC2,PC3,PC4,PC5,PC6,PC7.`

I don't care about `PC0,PC1,PC2,PC3.`
I want to set the bits according to truth table as mentioned :

```
             PC4    PC5   PC6 (Ports)
Row1 :        0      0     0         
Row2 :        0      0     1      
Row3 :        0      1     0      
Row4 :        0      1     1    
Row5 :        1      0     0     
Row6 :        1      0     1
```

The PC7 state should not be changed while setting the bit and should be untouched. I can set the bits individually, but need to set them at once.
Here is what I have done:

```
void Set(unsigned char Row)
{
  if(Row == 1)
  {
   PC_ODR &= ~(0x40) //To Set 0 to PC6
   PC_ODR &= ~(0x20) //To Set 0 to PC5
   PC_ODR &= ~(0x10) //To Set 0 to PC4
  }

  if(Row == 2) 
  {
   PC_ODR |= 0x40   //To Set 1 the PC6
   PC_ODR &= ~(0x20) //To Set 0 to PC5
   PC_ODR &= ~(0x10) //To Set 0 to PC4
  }

 // ......So on for Row 3, 4,5,6
}
```

For all the 6 rows, the code will become lengthy, is there any way I can use shift operator and AND / OR operator to get things done in short.

Comment: To set: `a |= (1 << bitpos)`, to unset: `a &= ~(1 << bitpos)`

Comment: I have done that already.

Comment: Use a lookup table indexed by row.

Comment: If you should write to the register only once, then you need to read from it once into a temporary variable, set and clear bits in the variable, and then write to the register once at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look close to your truth table and find some rules.

```
void Set(unsigned char Row){
    Row --;
    PC_ODR &= 0x8F;
    PC_ODR |= (0x01 & Row) << 6;
    PC_ODR |= (0x02 & Row) << 4;
    PC_ODR |= (0x04 & Row) << 2;
}
```

If you're supplying values 7 and 8 to `Row` this will still work, but may go wrong if you're supplying a number of 9 or up.

---

Thanks *[0andriy](/u/2511795)* for a minor improvement to the code!

Comment: You may use bits from `Row` directly: `result |= (Row & 0x2) << 4;` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

```
             PC654 Decimal
Row1 :        000    0     
Row2 :        100    4
Row3 :        010    2  
Row4 :        110    6
Row5 :        001    1 
Row6 :        101    5
```

Then using a lookup table:

```
void setRow(int row) {
  static int mask = 0x70; // binary mask for bits 456: 1110000
  static int rowData[7] = { 0/*dummy entry no row 0*/, 0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5 };
  PC_ODR = (PC_ODR & ~mask) | rowData[row]<<4; // get original bits except 456 and combine with right value for 456
}
```

Note: not sure about the types of your variables, but you may adapt easily.

Comment: The lut is small enough to be encoded in 24 bits using octal notation: `05162400 >> row & 7` which can be preshifted to align with the mask 8f.

Answer (score -1):

Pick any 8-bit reversing approach from here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious and wrap it into `reverse()`, then use this:

Assuming 0-based row-indexing (row 1 = 0) do

```
PC_ODR |= (0xf | (reverse(row) >> 1))
```

else id 1-based row-indexing (row 1 = 1) is needed do

```
PC_ODR |= (0xf | (reverse(row - 1) >> 1))
```

Comment: But you made it wrong. Note that bits 0,1,2 are mapped to 6,5,4, not 4,5,6

Comment: @iBug: Added the necessary preparations ... ;-)

Comment: @iBug: 1st reverse `row`, then use what I show on the result.